# How do I make Atom autocomplete local .js file names for imports?

Tags: atom-editor

I am a beginner about coding.
and I want to use Atom to coding.

I have one question.

See below picture.

I write "./pre but there is not presenter 
even if there is presenter.js file.

how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The completion of file paths is not core functionality of Atom, but you can install third-party packages such as [`autocomplete-paths`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-paths) to add it.